function pointer to call function with given arguments
I have the need to call a function with a given interface, in the following I'm trying to give an oversimplified example of the problem:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string f1(std::pair <int,int> a, int b) {
    int result = (a.first - a.second) * b;
    std::string s = std::to_string(result);
    s.append(" is the result!");
    return s;
}

std::string f2(std::pair <int,int> a, int b) {
    int result = (a.first - a.second) * b;
    std::string s = std::to_string(result);
    s.insert(0,"the result is ").append("!");
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::pair<int, int> direct{10, 3};
    std::pair<int, int> inverse{direct.second,direct.first};
    std::cout << f1(direct, 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f2(inverse, 2) << std::endl;
}

Now, my interfaces are like
std::string fun1(int b);
std::string fun2(int b);

and they should be used to call
f1(direct, b);

and
f2(inverse, b);

respectively.
It's the first time I'm diving into C++, hence I'm a bit confused. I understand I should be able to solve this with function pointers, but I am stuck at this point.
Second, rather than f1 and f2 I'd like to use a common function f and be able to change the "post processing" part (i.e. the s.append ... or s.insert ...) depending on the fun1 or fun2 call above.
I hope I was clear enough to get some help

What is your problem exactly? This code compiles and gives some output https://godbolt.org/z/nqxjvYPMx. Isn't it what your expecting? We don't see any use of fun1 or fun2 in your example.

Maybe show us how do you expect to use fun1 and fun2 and what should their results be. Your problem isn't clear to me either

Side note ; If you're not template programming... don't use std::pair, just create a struct with two int members with semantically meaningful names.

Clearly I wasn't clear enough :-) Thanks @Oersted, the output you see is just what I am expecting. But it seems to me (the example is very simplified, as I said) that I am violating the DRY rule. Besides that, I am forced to use this calls: fun1(int b) and fun2(int b), and they should be equivalent to f1(direct, b) and f2(inverse, b).

It sounds like you are trying to solve a problem with an overcomplicated solution. Could you try to explain the actual problem you are trying to solve rather than the supposed solution you are looking for?

@AndréLehto I have no real "problem" to be solved. I am studying C++ and trying to elaborate on some exercises, which is the way I usually learn things. The question I am asking is: is there a way to avoid rewriting the same lines in two functions (i.e.  int result = (a.first - a.second) * b;     std::string s = std::to_string(result); in this case) just because a minor part is different among the two (i.e. the s.append ...) part.
Second, does something like a "function alias" exist, like: std::string fun1(int b) = f1(direct, b) (I know the syntax is completely wrong).

Something with a lambda like auto fun1 = [=](int b){return f1(direct, b};}; ? Or something with std::bind? But if you need an actual function pointer, this is not quite it.
